# JSForce describeGlobal isn't working when the community has an added URL

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, jsforce

I have to be able to get all objects on my salesforce community and whenever i utilize the jsforce library to get the connection by using this method "jsforce.Connection" later on, i try to obtain every object on that community by using the "describeGlobal" method on the connection i just obtained. This works fine whenever my community has no added URL, however when it does have an added URL, The describeGlobal method doesn't work and throws a http 503 error. Every bit of help would be much appreciated.